# Vue parent component not re-rendering when computed properties are changing

Tags: vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a `User-Select` component that wraps a [v-select](https://vue-select.org/guide/options.html). This components job is to fetch list of users as user types and allow the user to select one or more users.
Here is the code for this component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select
      id="recipients"
      name="recipients"
      :options="options"
      label="name"
      multiple
      @search="onSearch"
      v-model="selectedVal"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
import axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'lodash'
export default {
  name: 'UserSelect',
  components: {
    'v-select': vSelect
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedVal: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(val) {
        //this.value = val
        this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch(search, loading) {
      loading(true)
      this.search(loading, search, this)
    },
    setSelected: function(val) {
      this.$emit('input', val)
    },
    search: _.debounce((loading, search, vm) => {
      axios
        .post('searchPeople', { search }, { useCredentails: true })
        .then(res => {
          vm.options = res.data
          loading(false)
        })
    }, 350)
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import url('https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest/dist/vue-select.css');
</style>
```

As you can see I have a v-model linked to a computed property , which emits input event. Also my property name is `value`. Hence, I expect the parent component,that is using this UserEvent component to be able to v-model.

[image: Edit elastic-fast-t3pti]

In the parent component , i have a computed property to which I have v-modelled the selected value. Here is the code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-modal id="editMessage" :title="title" :static="true">
      <form id="newMessageForm" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="to" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">To:</label>
            <user-select
              class="col-sm-7"
              style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px"
              v-model="editedMessage.recipients"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="subject" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"
              >Subject:</label
            >
            <input
              id="subject"
              name="subject"
              type="text"
              class="form-control col-sm-7"
              :value="editedMessage.messageSubject"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="date" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"
              >Schedule for later :
            </label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="form-control col-sm-7"
              v-model="scheduleForLater"
              id="scheduleCheckBox"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" v-if="scheduleForLater">
            <label for="date" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"
              >Scheduled Date:</label
            >
            <datetime
              v-model="editedMessage.sentDate"
              type="datetime"
              class="col-sm-17"
              input-class="form-control col-sm-15"
              input-id="date"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="body" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea
              id="body"
              name="body"
              type="text"
              rows="10"
              class="form-control col-sm-7"
              :value="editedMessage.messageBody"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <template v-slot:modal-footer="{ hide }">
        <!-- Emulate built in modal footer ok and cancel button actions -->

        <b-button size="sm" variant="light" @click="hide()">
          Cancel
        </b-button>
        <b-button
          size="sm"
          variant="secondary"
          @click="
            sendMessage(true)
            hide()
          "
        >
          Save Draft
        </b-button>
        <b-button
          size="sm"
          variant="primary"
          @click="
            sendMessage(false)
            hide()
          "
        >
          Send
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import UserSelect from '@/components/UserSelect.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'NewMessage',
  components: {
    'user-select': UserSelect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: [],
      scheduleForLater: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {},
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      openMessage: state => state.message.openMessage,
      messageAction: state => state.message.messageAction
    }),
    editedMessage: {
      get() {
        if (this.messageAction === 'new') {
          return this.newMessage()
        } else if (this.messageAction === 'reply') {
          let openMessageClone = Object.assign({}, this.openMessage)
          // make sender as the recipient.
          return Object.assign(openMessageClone, {
            messageSubject: 'RE: ' + this.openMessage.messageSubject,
            recipients: [
              {
                name: this.openMessage.sender.name,
                id: this.openMessage.sender.id
              }
            ]
          })
        } else {
          let openMessageClone = Object.assign({}, this.openMessage)
          return Object.assign(openMessageClone, {
            messageSubject: 'FW: ' + this.openMessage.messageSubject
          })
        }
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    },
    title() {
      if (this.messageAction === 'new') {
        return 'New'
      } else if (this.messageAction === 'reply') {
        return 'Reply'
      } else {
        return 'Forward'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    newMessage() {
      return {
        messageBody: '',
        messageSubject: '',
        recipients: [],
        sender: {}
      }
    },
    sendMessage(saveOrUpdateDraft) {
      var url = ''
      var message = {
        recipients: this.editedMessage.recipients.map(x => x.id),
        subject: this.editedMessage.messageSubject,
        body: this.editedMessage.messageBody,
        sentDate: this.scheduleForLater ? this.editedMessage.sentDate : null,
        id: ['editDraft', 'viewScheduled'].includes(this.messageAction)
          ? this.editedMessage.messageId
          : null
      }
      // id indiciates message id of draft message if one was opened.
      if (saveOrUpdateDraft) {
        // if no changes have been made to an opened draft, or the draft is completely empty for a new or existing draft , just go back.
        if (message.id) {
          url = `updateDraft`
        } else {
          url = 'saveNewDraft'
        }
      } else {
        if (message.id) {
          url = `sendSavedMessage`
        } else {
          url = 'sendMessage'
        }
      }
      axios
        .post(`eventdirect/${url}`, message, {
          withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (url.includes('Draft') && this.messageAction === 'viewScheduled') {
            this.$store.dispatch('sent/moveToDraft', response.data)
          } else if (url.includes('Draft')) {
            this.$store.dispatch('drafts/updateDraft', response.data)
          } else {
            // else part is sending a message or scheduling a draft.
            if (this.messageAction === 'editDraft') {
              this.$store.dispatch('drafts/deleteDraft', response.data)
            }
            // if we are sending an existing scheduled messsage , just update the sent vuex store , so that the message moves from scheduled to sent bucket.
            if (this.messageAction === 'viewScheduled') {
              this.$store.dispatch('sent/updateMessage', response.data)
            } else {
              this.$store.dispatch('sent/addSentItem', response.data)
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // TODO , add a qtip here to notify user , this message should be sent later.
          // messages in draft store with target , should be posted to the target
          this.$store.dispatch('drafts/updateDraft', {
            ...message,
            target: url
          })
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now i can see in the vue dev tools the computed values in this `NewMessage` component gets changed. However this component does not re-render and the selected values are not passed down to `UserSelect` component until I toggle , schedule for later checkbox , that causes the components data to change and this triggers the Vue component to suddenly start showing the selected values.

Whats going on here. There is something about Vue's reactivity that I am not able to understand here.

Thanks in anticipation. You can try it [here](https://t3pti.csb.app/), or click on the edit sandbox button above to view and edit the code.

To try it, click on the Vue Message link , then hit reply , then type ‘Test’ and then select ‘Test User’ from the drop down. The selected user wont show until you click the checkbox - Schedule later.

**PS: Within the component , UserSelect, In the setter of the computed property selectedVal , if I manually set the value of property value (by simply uncommenting line 39 - which is commented right now) , everything works fine. However , I get a warning that property should not be directly set. Since I am emitting the input event , parent component should change its v-model and re-render , thereby causing child component to re-render. Please correct me , if my understanding is wrong. Problem once again is that the parent component’s v-model changes , but it doesn’t re-render.**

[image]

Comment: Try changing `vm.options = res.data` to `this.options = res.data`

Comment: isn't `vm` same as `this`. I am passing `this` current vue component as the third argument to the lodashed function, I will still give it a try.